# FrameLayout width is not equal to its parent which is a Toolbar

Tags: android, width, android-toolbar, android-framelayout

[image: frame layout showing actual width and desired width by red arrow]

i have a frameLayout inside toolbar now problem is i set framelayout width to match patent but its not going to equal it wherease toolbar is full length
my code is as follows

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.ecbclass.user_activity.Home">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/app_title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="ECB Class"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl">

            </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_home" />
```

please suggest me way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add few lines (`contentInsetLeft` and `contentInsetStart`) into `Toolbar` and you're done:-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp" />
```